# How to use functions inside useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a function that gets users location and puts it into redux store.

```
export async function getLocation() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();

  if (status !== "granted") {
    setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
    return;
  }

  let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
    maximumAge: 1000,
  });

  dispatch(
    setLocation({
      longitude: location?.coords?.longitude,
      latitude: location?.coords?.latitude,
    })
  );
}
```

I want to use this function inside the useEffect hook so I can take users location when they open up the application. But when I put the function inside useEffect it throws an *Invalid Hook Call* error. I wanna solve this problem and if you have any other opinions on getting users location I will be glad to hear them.

```
const Navigation = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getLocation();
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStackScreen />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};


export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Navigation />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

The code sample I mentioned is above.

```
versions:
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
```

Comment: Don't make `getLocation` call `useDispatch`. Either pass `dispatch` in as an argument (or just make a closure over it, similar to how you use `setErrorMsg` and `setLocation`), or make a real `useGetLocation` hook that returns a function to call.

Comment: You can see a simple example here: https://hoanguyenit.com/build-a-shopping-cart-with-react-redux.html  using react+ redux